# How can I recover from Access Denied Error on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to host a public facing static website on AWS S3.

1. I logged into the AWS console from my root account
2. Created a new bucket and uploaded few static HTML files
3. Under {Bucket-name}->Permissions->Bucket Policy, I have provided the below policy

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow", 
            "Principal": "*", 
            "Action": "s3:GetObject", 
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]/*" 
        } 
    ] 
}

I keep getting the Access denied error.

[image]

Comment: A simple Google search can also return Amazon docs. I am trying to follow the below tutorial and enabling website hosting is the step you perform after editing bucket policy.

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-1/

Comment: try to allow resources `arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]/*`, though I'd advice using a GUI option on the bucket to host a website, the gui should set the correct policy for you

Answer (score 0):

Try `"Principal" : "*"` in bucket policy and also you need to add `s3:ListBucket` permission to be able to list the bucket. ListBucket permission needs to be added as separate statement in the policy.